# how to apply Big M to model the logic constraint （if-then-else）

Tags: optimization, logical-constraints, big-m

I was hoping to get some help in modelling the following logic as an MIP Constraint

[image]

c_{m,l}^{RC} is binary decision variable.
Simplify it：

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You want to model $y=1 \iff x > 0$.  The following big-M constraints enforce that relationship, where $\epsilon>0$ is a small tolerance:
$$\epsilon y \le x \le M y$$

Because your $x$ is integer, you can take $\epsilon = 1$.

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt